# change label color textFormField on focus when floating Label Behavior is auto in the flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-textformfield

change label color TextFormField on focus when floating Label Behavior is auto in  the flutter

[image that focus node is off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqhk3.png)

[image that focus node is on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoVIm.png)

I want a solution to this issue in the flutter

Comment: You want to change label color when focused?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

Refer Textfield [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html)

Refer InputDecoration [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)

```
Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
       // hintText: 'Enter Name here',
        labelText: 'First Name',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

[image]

Comment: it's not my answer and thanks for your answering

Comment: what do you exact want?

Comment: when `floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto` i cant change label color with changing focus node